# How can I see my System details in a Graphical way? (in Lubuntu)

Tags: lubuntu, ram, system, cpu, system-info

I am new to LUbuntu. In Windows, if I want to know my system properties, I see it by going to Control Panel and clicking on the System icon.

What are the equivalents of these features in LUbuntu, where a user can see his system properties and hardware configuration, like RAM, CPU/processor, hard disk capacity, etc.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its called "system profiler and benchmark", and can be found under system tools

[image]

Comment: I didn't find "system profiler and benchmark" under System Tools in my recent install of Lubuntu. But you can install it using the "Discover" app (also under System Tools).
I used the search box in Discover and entered "system profiler" and it appeared at the top of the list.